# $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable and $\{S \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N}) \mid S \text{ is finite} \}$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

I know you can prove the first proposition with a variation of Cantor's diagonal argument. Is the following a sufficiently rigorous or even correct proof too?

Consider the interval $(0,1)$ in the real numbers. The decimal places of each number in this interval are countable, as each decimal place is located at a position with a natural number valued index. For each number

$$r = 0 \cdot 10^{0} + k_1 \cdot 10^{-1} + k_2 \cdot 10^{-2} + \dots \in (0,1) \text{ where $k_i \in \{0,1, \dots, 9\}$}$$

it holds true, that the number

$$ n = k_1 \cdot 10^{1} + k_2 \cdot 10^{2} + \dots \in \N$$

corresponds to $r$'s decimal places digit by digit (edit: in reverse order). But

$$\{n\} \in \mathcal{P}(\N)$$

So therefore there exists an injection

$$(0,1) \rightarrowtail \mathcal{P}(\N)$$

which maps each $r$ onto that $\{n\}$ the $n$ of which digit by digit corresponds to the decimal places of $r$. (edit: in reverse order) Hence there are at least as many elements in $\mathcal{P}(\N)$ as in $(0,1)$. But $(0,1)$ is uncountably infinite, so $\mathcal{P}(\N)$ too must be uncountable.

This certainly is not very pretty, as it argues based on the string representations of the numbers rather than the numbers themselves, but is it even valid to do this?

Another doubt I have about this stems from the fact that I think you can also argue the following:

The set $M = \{S \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N}) \mid S \text{ is finite} \}$ also includes the elements $\{n_i\}$ that we just used to argue that $\mathcal{P}(\N)$ is uncountable. $M$ includes these $\{n_i\}$ because these are finite sets. So therefore $M$ would be uncountable by the above argument. Which it is not.

So somewhere in here is an error. Is it in the first proof or the second?

Comment: Using your argument, what is the set you are assigning to $1/9$?

Comment: The set $\{11111 \dots\}$. Why? That set is a singleton in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is it not?

Comment: No, clearly it is not.

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like you're mapping each number in the interval $(0,1)$ to a one-element set $\{x\}\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N).$ Is that right? So you're actually showing that the set of all one-element subsets of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable?

Comment: yes, that is what I am doing.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Why not?

Comment: So your mapping takes a number $t\in(0,1)$ and moves the decimal point all the way over to the right? So $t\mapsto t*10^\infty$? No, that's not it, because you're also reversing the order of the digits.

Comment: yes, that would be an equivalent construction I think, if that is allowed.

Comment: @bof Where am I reversing the order of the digits?

Comment: $$r=0.123=1\cdot10^{-1}+2\cdot10^{-2}+3\cdot10^{-3}\mapsto1\cdot10^1+2\cdot10^2+3\cdot10^3=3210$$

Comment: @bof Oh right. That was an oversight in the construction. Does not change anything fundamentally though.

Comment: How are you defining $11111\dots$? As the decimal digits in $1/9$ are unending, it seems you're referring to a number written as an infinite sequence of $1$'s, but that isn't a natural number.

Comment: @BrianYao Why is that not a natural number?

Comment: It'll probably work.  But my advice.  Get out of thinking in terms of decimals.  The advantage that you are familiar with them is *vastly* outweighed by the disadvantage that the are clunky, arbitrary and completely artificial.  You are asking about subsets of N, so *use* subsets of N.   if you have a countable list $S_i$ then either $S_i$ has $i$ as an element or not.  Make a now set $V = \{i \in \mathbb N| i \not \in S_i\}$.  That's it, $V$ can not be one your list.  No need to convert to and from decimals.

Comment: The notation isn't that of a natural number. Natural numbers have finite values and so have finite digit representations. So a natural number with an infinite number of digits isn't allowed. To give another angle, the value, as you have defined it, is $\sum_{i = 0}^\infty 10^i$ which diverges to positive infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that the number n=k1⋅101+k2⋅102+⋯∈N corresponds to r 's decimal places digit by digit (edit: in reverse order).

But $r$ has an infinite number of digits.  You can not reverse an infinite sequence.  (What would be the first element).

The only elements that are "reversible" are the finite decimals (or the periodic decimals), i.e. the rationals.  Hence you *don't* have an injection of $(0,1)$ into the power set but an injection of the *rational* numbers in $(0,1)$ into the power set and only into the subset of the Power set that has only finite sets as elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll prove a fact which can be used to prove your result.

> $\mathcal{P}_n (\Bbb{N})=\{{S\subset \Bbb{N} | \text{card}(S)=n }\}$ is countable for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Consider the natural function $\Bbb{N}^n\to\cup_{1\le k\le n}\mathcal{P}_k (\Bbb{N})$ given by $(x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n)\to \{x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n\}.$ This is clearly surjective and therefore $$\text{card}(\mathcal{P}_n(\Bbb{N}))\le\text{card}(\cup_{1\le k\le n}\mathcal{P}_k (\Bbb{N}))\le\text{card}(\Bbb{N}^n)=\text{card}(\Bbb{N}).$$

Comment: That position is not a natural number, though, so I am not sure what this proves.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: I found my silly mistake and thank you for your help. What do you think about my edited answer?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially fine.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Also, I think we can reconstruct the previous construction considering the sum of elements of $S$ as: Consider all sets with sum of its elements is $1,$ arrange them in lexicographically. Then consider all sets with element sum $2$ and do the same ordering. Repeat the process infinitely. Now we have a unique (countable) arrangement of  $\{S \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N}) | S \text{ is finite} \},$ aren't we?